# Как использовать запись curl в практике

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

Есть код curl

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
-F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
-F to=bar@example.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Этот код предлагается для отправки писем через mailgun. Но я не могу понять как это применить в реальности php, где есть curl_init(),curl_setopt(),curl_exec() и curl_close().

Answer (score 0):

```
          $url      = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/wdpst.ru/messages';
      $userpwd  = 'api:key-XXXX';
      foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
      $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
```